How can I install NetHunter on a Nokia Lumina 635?
I want to run NetHunter on a Nokia lumina 635, but the NetHunter page only has distros for a Nokia 6.1 and 3.1. So is there a way to put NetHunter on a Nokia lumina 635? Maybe by first putting android on it?

Nokia lumina 635 is way older, it has only 512MB RAM, where as Nokia 3.1 has at minimum 2GB and Nokia 6.1 3GB.

Sorry, I'm closing this question because the phone doesn't run on Android, but on Windows Phone. I'd migrate this question to [windowsphone.se] if it hadn't been closed. Unfortunately, there's no site for general mobile phones.

No
The Nokia Lumina 635 was released in 2014. It's the 4G-compatible version of the Lumina 630. It has only 512MB RAM and 8GB of storage, which are not enough for a modern version of Android, which NetHunter is based on.
It is also a Windows Phone device, which means the boot mechanism is different from conventional Android designs. Nobody appears to have produced an Android ROM for it, even when it was current hardware.
It might be of interest to a 'phone collector, but there isn't much else it would be useful for.

Ah. I see. Well as a phone collector I suppose I can get some use out of it.
